# wp7 - stringformat change imperial and metric for textblock stringformat

Tags: windows-phone-7, string-formatting, metric

Hi everyone i have done something not so good i should say. Now when my application is in the final stage and near complete i need to have a settings page where i can set if the units of measure should be imperial or metric.

The problem i now have is that i have 20 textblock that are bound to different sliders like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="spring" Text="Spring" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat='0.00 inch', ElementName=springslider}" Margin="300,-21,0,0" x:Name="springData" />
<Slider Name="springslider" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Maximum="1" Minimum="0" SmallChange="5" />
```

In the textblock text binding i have set the StringFormat to 0.00 inchs and if i choose metric i want it to change the stringformat to 0.0 mm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Write a string converter class which will take the value and return you a different value according to the settings property that you set - something similar to this:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (Settings.FormatSetting == FormatSettings.Metric)
            return (string)value + " mm";
        else return (string)value + " inch";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then add the converter to one of your resource dictionaries:

```
<common:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
```

And then use it when binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ElementName=springslider}" Margin="300,-21,0,0" x:Name="springData" />
```

Comment: what if i need to change the decimal from 0.0 to 0.000? because 1.0 mm is 0.039 inches

Comment: Instead of just converting to string and attaching "mm" or "inch", first convert the value passed to the converter to a double and then convert it to string in a particular format (0.00 or 0.0000) depending on the chosen system (metric or imperial). Search the Internet for string formatting for decimal numbers if you don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: Have a quick question, why cant i have this if (Settings.ListPickerSetting == 1)
                return (string)value + " mm";
            if (Settings.ListPickerSetting == 2)
                return (string)value + " inch";

getting this error
'StringFormatConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: i found this for the double formating but cant get how to implement it
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: The error itself explains the issue - not all code paths return a value. Use 'else', because when you use 2 'if's, it may happen that none of those execute.

Comment: yeah so i must have return default. But i still have an error that says "InvalidCastException was unhandled"

Comment: yeah so i must have return default. But i still have an error that says "InvalidCastException was unhandled" and i did get this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx but i still dont know how to solve it.

Comment: anyone have some more feedback

Comment: This is what i read 
For a conversion from a Single or a Double to a Decimal, the source value is infinity, Not-a-Number (NaN), or too large to be represented as the destination type.


A failure occurs during an explicit reference conversion.

 
For an explicit reference conversion to be successful, the source value must be null and what i get of this is that null = 0 so whats wrong.